# I would like to add a google adsense banner to my wordpress without it affecting the positioning of the 2 sidebars (1 on left and 1 on right).

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, adsense

I would like to add a google adsense banner to my wordpress without it affecting the positioning of the 2 sidebars (1 on left and 1 on right). I added the google adsense code to the heder sidebar but that just pushes everything else down (position wise) but I would not like for this to happen. I would want only the content in the center to be pushed down and the positioning of both the sidebars to remain the same.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as the error you describe is dependent on the WP theme you're using.  You will need to expand your question to include some way to replicate the problem.

Comment: I am using the QA Engine theme - http://www.demo.enginethemes.com/qaengine

Answer (score 0):

First.  I'm assuming you're adding your adsense code in a text widget?

Wrap the ad sense code in this div inside the text widget (adjust the height for your ad, I'm assuming 728 x 90 or 970 x 90:

```
<div style="position: absolute;height: 100px; left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); transform: translateX(-50%);>

// PLACE YOUR ADSENSE CODE HERE

</div>
```

Then to your custom CSS file, add something like this (where margin-top is at least enough to give you the breathing room you want below the ad:

```
.row.select-category {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I added the following inside the TEXT widget - <div style="position: absolute;height: 100px; left: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); transform: translateX(-50%);>

// PLACE YOUR ADSENSE CODE HERE

</div>   

And then I added 

.main-blog-fix {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

to my css file

Comment: I looked at the wrong page.  You want to use this class : .row.select-category not .main-blog-fix. I updated the answer.  This is all assuming that you're using the theme that refers to the link you provided in your question.